# Getting library not found for -lstdc++.6 while building the Mfp 6.3 Iphone App in Xcode 10.1

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, xcode10.1

Getting this error when running any MFP 6.3 app in Xcode 10.1:

> Showing All Issues :-1: library not found for -lstdc++.6
>
> :-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The same is working in Xcode 9.0/Xcode 8.0 version.

How this issue can be particularly solved for IBM Mobilefirst 6.3 iPhone Apps. Also, Apple Store is not accepting build made with Xcode 9.0. Also tried MFP 6.3 latest fix but it is not solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

MobileFirst 6.3 doesn't support iOS 12/Xcode 10 - you should upgrade to MobileFirst 7.1 or 8.0. 
Having said that, you can try the solution given in this link ( https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/07/23/mfp-support-for-ios12/#known-issues )

Answer (score 1):

lstdtc++ is deprecated in recent versions. I have faced this issue and it is resolved after following the steps mentioned in https://github.com/Kila2/libstdc-.6.0.9.tbd

Download the Files from Github
1. For simulator to work, copy the files from iPhoneSimulator to path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/"
2. For actual devices to work, copy the files from iPhoneOS to paths as mentioned in the link w.r.t Xcode version.

I did the same and restart XCode. It works post this.

Comment: Consider editing your post and describing those steps mentioned in link.

Comment: I have added more info.